# Kibana - Add Geopoint information to index

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have an elasticsearch index with information about business operations of my company. Some of these requests have details about the office that process the request. The office is a code number like Office 1, 2, 3...Not all requests contains the office data.

I like to draw the requests in a geographic map with Kibana. So I like to add location information to the index. Is it posible to create a scripted field that from the office number returns a fixed location point and use that point to draw the point in a map?

For example:

Office 1: Lat: 53.43, Lon: 32.32
Office 2: Lat: 34.43, Lon: 12.32
...

Is there other way to add this information to the index without actually modifying it? For example, having a separete index with the office locations and joinig the two indices in a query.

I can´t figgure a way to do it without modifiying the index.

Thanks Javier!!!!

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you cant add this data to your existing index? Adding new data fields to indexes is pretty easy.